# Date conversion error in Sql

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I get error:

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

I call the stored procedure like this:

```
var result = (from x in db.spStoredProc(sStart, sEnd) select x).ToList();
```

where `sStart` and `sEnd` are strings with this value:

```
sStart = "CONVERT(date,GETDATE())"
```

and

```
sEnd = "DATEADD(d,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))"
```

The stored procedure has two parameters of type `varchar(max)`

In the stored procedure I make left join and I use them like this:

```
where date_expire >= @sStartSQL AND date_expire < @sEndSQL
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: You're probably mixing date formats (US and EU for example) so when you try to convert from a string it fails.

Comment: @ChrisF Ok and how to fix this?

Comment: Store all dates as dates (not strings) and make sure you set up the locale properly when converting to and from strings.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? *SQL* is **not** a product - it's a query language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass literals as parameters.  So SQL Server literally tries to cast this to date:

```
sEnd = "DATEADD(d,1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))"
```

Instead, pass:

```
sEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

as parameter.